# Vagrant Private Boxfile generated via Packer/Atlas is 404 when accessed as logged in user

Tags: vagrant, packer, atlas

I'm generating an AMI image, and passing that through to a vmware_fusion vagrant.box post-processor. This completes successfully, and the vagrant box page claims that the box is accessible and available. Using the instructions provided on the box file page to init a new project with the box result in...

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

When copy/pasting the 404'd URL into a browser, I also get the Atlas 404 page.

I have verified that I am logged in via `vagrant login` at the console and I am logged in to the Atlas site, so the 404 is not a result of the box being private and myself not being logged in.

I have run other box builds, and they did successfully download at this stage. It kind of seems like Packer/Atlas is bugged right now, but I have no way to verify that.

Here's what my Packer config looks like:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS`}}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET`}}"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "ami_name": "ami_name_here {{timestamp}}",
      "instance_type": "t2.medium",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "source_ami": "ami-df38e6b4",
      "user_data_file": "ec2-setup.sh"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant' | {{.Vars}} sudo -S -E bash '{{.Path}}'",
      "script": "packer_scripts/setup.sh"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "sleep 30",
        "cd /tmp && sudo wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb",
        "sudo dpkg -i /tmp/puppetlabs-release-pc1-trusty.deb",
        "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y",
        "sudo apt-get install puppet -y"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "puppet-masterless",
      "manifest_file": "manifests/default.pp",
      "module_paths": [
        "modules/"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "type": "atlas",
        "artifact": "my/artifact",
        "artifact_type": "amazon.ami",
        "metadata": {
          "created_at": "{{timestamp}}"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "atlas",
        "artifact": "my/artifact",
        "artifact_type": "vagrant.box",
        "metadata": {
          "created_at": "{{timestamp}}",
          "provider": "vmware_fusion"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "push": {
    "name": "my/artifact",
    "vcs": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more digging I found [more complete documentation](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/packer/artifacts) about how the Packer/Atlas process works. It would seem that Atlas cannot accept an AMI image built from a Packer Builder and convert that into a VM image for other platforms (VMware, Virtualbox). Which is unfortunate, since my builds complete much more quickly on my own EC2 instance.

If I'm incorrect here I'd love to know how it can be done. If I find a way, I'll be back to update.